# Change value in private member in JFrame with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

**Hello,**

I have the following code, what I want is to modify the value of the instance called number to any value

I have both classes in the same package

**ReflectionOnClass.class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ReflectionOnClass extends JFrame {

private int number = 2;
private JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("X: " + number);

public ReflectionOnClass() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    add(jLabel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**ExecReflection.class**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ExecReflection {

private static final String C = "ReflectionOnClass";

public ExecReflection() {

    try {
        final Field field = Class.forName(C).getDeclaredField("number");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        final ReflectionOnClass rF = new ReflectionOnClass();
        field.set(rF , 100);
        mostrar("Value number: " + field.get(rF));
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

 public <T> void mostrar(final T t){System.out.println(t);}
 public static void main(String ...gaga) {
    final Runnable r = ExecReflection::new;
    r.run();
 }
}
```

the output is the correct as in the image but in the JFrame there is no

[image: result]

*there is no possibility to change the value of said variable before the JFrame starts?*

***Update*** this was what I wanted, to modify the value before the JFrame started, but with reflection

```
final Field field = Class.forName(C).getDeclaredField("jLabel");
field.setAccessible(true);
if(field.getType() == JLabel.class) {
  final JLabel j = (JLabel)field.get(ReflectionOnClass.class.newInstance());
  j.setText("X: " + 5000);
}
```

[image]

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do? As you are changing value of field inside instance of "RleflectionOnClass" instance you created here that you don't use anywhere, it isn't used in that GUI application at all, so why it should change?

Comment: that the change is also reflected in the jframe, as investigated, can be done with instrumentation invoking the premain, am I right?, I want to modify that field before the classloader uploads it to the jvm.

Comment: You just need to use reflection to access actual field with that data...so you need to get instance of that object, you didn't write what exactly you need to change, so it is impossible to us to tell you how exactly do this. Provide real code that you need to reflect

Comment: @GotoFinal ReflectionOnClass.class this is the class I want to make reflection, it is exposed in the original post thnks :D

Answer (score 0):

Its possible.
You can add this functions to ReflectionOnClass:

```
public void setNumber(int num){
    this.number = num;
    label.setText("X: " + this.number);
}

public int getNumber(){
    return this.number;
}
```

and just call them from ExecReflection:

```
final ReflectionOnClass rF = new ReflectionOnClass();
rF.setNumber(4);
System.out.println("Value number: " + rF.getNumber());
```

Comment: do not explain me well, in the real application I do not have access to the class ReflextionOnClass, should I use the ClassLoader and modify it in runtime?, Before the jframe starts ?? Thnks

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is changing because you are not actually changing value that is displayed

```
private int number = 2;
private JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("X: " + number);
```

You need to access `jLabel` field, as this is your displayed value, and change text to something else, if `number` is used in other places, then you probably need to change both of them, so `number` to this example 100 value, and `jLabel` text to `X: 100`

Comment: something like that ? try {
            final Field field = Class.forName(C).getDeclaredField("jLabel");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            final ReflectionOnClass rF = new ReflectionOnClass();
            final JLabel j = new JLabel();
            j.setText("X: " + 100);
            field.set(rF , j);
            mostrar("Value number: " + field.get(rF));
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: @RubénEspinoza you can just get instance of that label using reflections and change text using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText(java.lang.String)